# Python class multiple-inheritance with __init__ function

Tags: python-3.x, class

I would like to have each class to have different or same variables and inherit with final class as below

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def add(self):
        return self.x + self.y

 class b(object):
    def __init__(self, u, v):
        self.u = u
        self.v = v

    def mul(self):
        return self.u*self.v

class c(a, b):
    def __init__(self,x,y,u,v,w):
        super(c,self).__init__(x,y,u,v,w)
        self.w = w

    def div(self):
        return (self.x+self.y+self.u+self.v)/self.w
```

Error as:

```
ob = c(1,2,3,4,5)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-20-0c1a3250f4a1>", line 1, in <module>
ob = c(1,2,3,4,5)

File "<ipython-input-19-5734ec980138>", line 20, in __init__
super(c,self).__init__(x,y,u,v,w)

TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

How to fix error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is good practice but you can make it work by calling the `__init__()` for each superclass separately.

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def add(self):
        return self.x + self.y

class b(object):
    def __init__(self, u, v):
        self.u = u
        self.v = v

    def mul(self):
        return self.u*self.v

class c(a, b):
    def __init__(self,x,y,u,v,w):
        a.__init__(self, x, y)
        b.__init__(self, u, v)
        self.w = w

    def div(self):
        return (self.x+self.y+self.u+self.v)/self.w

k = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

print(k.div())
>>>2.0
print(k.add())
>>>3
print(k.mul())
>>>12
```